# When declaring and initiating alert with wait in selenium webdriver Type mismatch: cannot convert from Alert to Alert error is coming up

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In the following code though i have declared and intialized an alert in selenium webdriver following error is coming up in selenium webdriver.

```
Alert action = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

In the above alert

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Alert to Alert

is coming up though the above alert is declared correctly.

Comment: first line should be wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()); followed by Alert action = driver.switchToalert();

Comment: What import did you use for `Alert`?

Comment: can you add full stack trace of exception?

Comment: @santhoshkumar not required. `alertIsPresent` returns `driver.switchTo().alert()`

Comment: @GaurangShah  then i think, there are two alert classes coming into play, one is Alert alert object reference variable and another is the alert class returned by the expectedcoditions. both may refer to the different class with the same name "alert". at Jayant can you check updating the webdriver and selenium standalone... This is just a thought and i am not sure

Comment: @santhoshkumar that's preciously the case.

Comment: My issue is solved.The issue is instead importing alert from org.selenium package is imported a class with different package.Now the issue is solved.Thanks everyone for your help.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As per your question you have provided the following line of code:

```
Alert action = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

Syntactically you are pretty correct.

Observe the following snapshot of the code block, the call to `alertIsPresent()` is returning back `ExpectedCondition<Alert>` which we have to assign to an object of `Alert` class only, which you did through your code.

[image]

Now coming to the error part as you are seeing **`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Alert to Alert`**

The most probable reason can be your incomplete code or the missing imports. For this line of code to work you must be having the following:

1. Initiate an instance of `WebDriverWait` before you use the instance.
2. Make the proper `imports`
3. An example:

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
   //your code
   WebDriverWait wait8 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   Alert action = wait8.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
   ```

Through this you should see off the error.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: thanks @DebanjanB.It worked for me.There is a import issue with the package.Now the code is perfectly alright